# Repetitive Joomla fields?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.2

Is there possible to make repetitive infinite number of fields in Joomla extension settings?Firstly it should show only one field, but if user needs then could easily with button push get another one and another one - as much as he needs.

I am making a slider extension with images and I can't know how many images the user will need and I don't want to strict him only to ten images for example.

Comment: You should create a custom form element that does what you want.

Comment: In that case I create two custom field types: button and image. If user presses on the button then Joomla adds another input field in extension settings. What class and method should I call to add requested additional input field? @MasterAM

Comment: I don't think that there should be multiple field types. If you decide to extend the `JFormField` class, I think that you should create the entire UI and logic that allows you to upload the files (i.e, file form fields), the `add` button, probably `remove` buttons etc. This is not straight-forward and you will need some logic in your model (and probably in the controller, too) to make it work. The other way is creating your form directly in your view's template.

Comment: There is major work being put into producing this for Joomla 3.2 if not then 3.5. It has been mostly done but a lot of testing and fixes need to be made ;)

Comment: Excellent! Great news @Lodder! How I will know when I will be able to use it? Also how do you know this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Initial comment:**

```
There is major work being put into producing this for Joomla 3.2 if not then 3.5.
It has been mostly done but a lot of testing and fixes need to be made
```

**Update:**

This feature will be bought out with Joomla 3.2 which is going to be out around 1 months time. The feature will simply allow the admin to add multiple form fields and remove them at ease.

You can test this and possibly help towards debugging it here:

http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=30781